# why does my tomcat apache 8 show an empty page when i try to deploy a war file?

Tags: apache, tomcat, deployment, tomcat8

![enter image description here][1]why does my tomcat apache 8 show an empty page when i try to deploy a war file?

I have a war which is about 3 MB, but i done understand why after i click deploy, i am forwarded to this page.

what should i do to deploy it? i tried deploying other smaller war file, and it was deployed successfully, unlike with the war file that is larger than the working one.

is there any other way to deploy a war file?
i have a lib within the war, is it any issue? but if ever i remove the jars, the project would not work ofcourse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of this reasons:

1. java was compiled in 3.0
2. jars are conflicting.
3. leak on session.

solution.

1. you could explode / use winrar to extract WEB-INF, and past it to an existing working app.
2. recompile your project to 2.5 and export to war, this should work.